# set up cron using config.xml

Tags: cron

Hi i am tring to set up cron in magento using config.xml. but anyreason its not working, 
Here is the code which i am using.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </mycompany_mymodule>                         
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>mycompany_mymodule/observer::importproduct</model></run>
            </mycompany_mymodule>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
<?php  
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer {  
    public function Importproduct() {
        Mage::log('cron works!!',null,'cron.log');
    }  
}  ?>
```

but its not working, can anybody help me.
Thank you in advance..

Comment: Is your cron actually setup? is cron.php being called by your system's cron? Try running cron.php yourself.

Comment: i added Mage::log('test'); in my cron.php file, When i run www.mydomain.com/cron.php its giving output, but with this midule its not giving any output.

Comment: Is your module enabled in `app/etc/modules/`? In other words, did you check whether the module itself is loaded at all?

Comment: Thanx Rick,Yes i have this code in app/etc/modules...   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodules>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Mycompany_Mymodules>
    </modules>
</config>

Comment: Also, in your config.xml you reference this: `<run><model>mycompany_mymodule/observer::importproduct</model></run>` where you call the function *i*mportproduct and in your PHP code it's *I*mportproduct, note the capital.

Comment: ok..thank you Rick, but still its not working.. please anything else i need to do.. i want to run cron through only magento custom module, so i haven't add cron in cpanel, is that ok?

Comment: Play with cron jobs, play with 'AOE Scheduler' module: http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer with a collection of all the comments:

Is your cron actually setup? is cron.php being called by your system's cron? Try running cron.php yourself.

Is your module enabled in app/etc/modules/? In other words, did you check whether the module itself is loaded at all?

Also, in your config.xml you reference this: mycompany_mymodule/observer::importproduct where you call the function **importproduct** and in your PHP code it's **Importproduct**, note the capital I.

Comment: i make "importproduct" from "Importproduct" but still not getting any result

Comment: @Gmb did you clear your `var/cache/` after doing that?

Comment: no, i didn't,, but now i have done it.

Comment: And running cron.php now still doesn't result in any response? Is your log directory writable for it to write to `cron.log`? Check the `cron_schedule` table in your database, does it have entries from your module?

Comment: I also have added mail function after Mage::log(); in Observer.php, but i am not getting mail.

Comment: @Gmb Is your module visible in Magento backend System -> Configuration -> Advanced (all the way on the bottom left)?

Comment: fur running cron using config.xml, this is the sufficient code? or anything more require?

Comment: @Gmb Yes, I compared it to my config. The config you posted seems to be fine.

Comment: bad luck for me.. :(

Comment: @Gmb If my answer isn't your solution then please remove it as an accepted answer by clicking the check mark next to it again.

Comment: any server configuration is need to change?

Comment: i accepted your answer because you shown my 1 mistake to remove  first capital letter and make it lowercase.

Comment: @Gmb Server configuration is needed to eventually have the cron.php be executed regularly, for testing purposes executing cron.php is enough.

Comment: i am not running cron.php manually, i am just using this module to run cron.php..

Comment: @Gmb The purpose of cron.php is to run all the crons defind in `config.xml`. So you can't have it call itself.

Comment: then how can i run only this cron fuction. i want to run this function every 1 hour, for testing i have added for every 10 minits. please can you suggest me>... Thanx

Comment: @Gmb You have a couple options, either use a controller action which you call by URL. Or create a file where you load Magento and execute what you want to execute. Although I still don't understand why you don't want to just run cron.php every hour, that will execute your function and perhaps some others as well.

Comment: yes.. i want to run cron.php every hour, but it need to run through config.xml not from www.mydomain.com/cron.php ..... actually my requirement is that i want to create 1 separate module which will run my cron every hour using config.xml setting.i will not run run it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method name same as config.xml file, Like the below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </mycompany_mymodule>                         
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>mymodule/observer::importProduct</model></run>
            </mycompany_mymodule>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>

<?php  
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer {  
    public function importProduct() {
        Mage::log('cron works!!',null,'cron.log');
    }  
}
```